# How to get all matches with MongoDB $elemMatch?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database, nosql

I have two objects:

```
{
  genre: ['music', 'movie']
}
```

and

```
{
 genre: ['movie', 'music']
}
```

and my query is:

```
db.test.find({genre :{ $elemMatch:{ $in : ['movie']}}})
```

and it only gives me the second object. Why? I want to get all the docs that contain a specific genre in their arrays no matter where in the array. How can I do this?

Comment: Basically use `db.test.find({ "genre": { "$in": ["movie"] } })` or in fact just `db.test.find({ "genre": "movie" })` as the `$elemMatch` is not required unless you need multiple properties in the array sub-documents to match your conditions. Which of course you do not. And neither is the `$in`. Just because the content is in an "array" does not mean you need to use an operator that uses an array as arguments or inspection for a single value test.

Comment: Not based on the data you are giving here. There is nothing wrong with either query form ( just that it is superfluous to do anything other than the second example ). So if you don't match then there are other reasons of which you are not telling us here.

Comment: It works now, great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need neither `$elemMatch` nor `$in` in this case. A simple `field:value` will match documents where `field` is an array and any one of the values in that array is `value`. That means

```
db.test.find({genre :'movie'});
```

will suffice.

The array query operators are required in more complex situations.

- `$in` is needed when you have a list of possible values and want documents where *any* of them is found (so `db.test.find({genre : { $in:['movie']} });` would work, but would be needlessly convoluted)
- `$all` works like $in but requires that *all* provided elements are in the array
- `$elemMatch` is a bit more complex. It is required when you want to use multiple operator-conditions (like $gt or $lt) but want only those documents where one array entry matches *all* the conditions. Without the $elemMatch operator, you get results where each condition is met by at least one array entry, but not necessarily all by the same entry.

Answer (score 0):

Remember db.test.find() in general returns you cursor object. You can access all doc as follows:

```
entry = db.test.find({genre :{ $elemMatch:{ $in : ['movie']}}})
for doc in entry:
    print(doc)
```